# Pasar dos objetos por ajax mvc razor

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, mvc

Mi duda es la siguiente: resulta que estoy pasando un archivo file por `ajax` al controlador y lo recibo sin ningún problema.

Pero aparte del file también quiero pasar un parámetro que es un id. que también tengo que recibirlo en el mismo controlador, en el `ActionResult`, recibo sin problemas el archivo pero no logro mandar el id.
Alguna idea. es `RAZOR` con `MVC .Net`

**Codigo ajax:**

```js
function Grabar(id,input_group_) {
            console.log("Entré a  grabar con " + id + " y " + input_group_);

          
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                console.log("comenzare a buscar el archivo");
  
                var fileUpload = $(input_group_).get(0);  
                var files = fileUpload.files;  
              
                
                var fileData = new FormData();
                var id_query = id;

  
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
                    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);  
                }  
              
              
                console.log("comenzando carga");
                $.ajax({  
                    url: '/Acreditacion_Equipo/Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga',
                    type: "POST",  
                    contentType: false, 
                    processData: false,  
                    data: {id_query:id_query, fileData},
                   // data: fileData,id_query,
                    success: function (result) {  
                        alert(result);  
                    },  
                    error: function (err) {  
                        alert(err.statusText);  
                    }  
                });  
            } else {  
                alert("FormData no esta soportado");
                console.log("error no soportado");
            }
```

y en mi controlador `C#` recibo bien el archivo pero el `string` id lo recibo `null`

```
 public ActionResult Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga(string id_query)
    {
        string id_ = id_query;
        // Checking no of files injected in Request object  
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //  Get all files from Request object  
                HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
                    //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

                    HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                    string fname;

                    // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                    if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fname = file.FileName;
                    }

                    // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                    fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
                // Returns message that successfully uploaded  
                return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No files selected.");
        }
    }
```

No se porque esta pasando esto. alguna idea de como recibirlo ?

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos opciones para realizar lo que se está buscando.

**La primera es:** ya que se está enviando información desde un `FormData` y marcando la llamada `ajax` con un `contentType = false`. Lo que se necesita hacer es poner el id también el el `FormData`. En este caso algo así:

```
fileData.append('id_query', id);
```

Y hacer la llamada ajax solo con solo la variable FormData:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Acreditacion_Equipo/Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fileData,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }
});
```

En el back end, leer ese valor con:

```
public ActionResult Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga()
{
    var tmp = Request.Form["id_query"];
    ...
```

---

**La Segunda:** es poner el id en el `query string` (y sugeriría se mandara como id, para aprovechar la tabla de ruteo de `mvc`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Acreditacion_Equipo/Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga/'+  id_query,
```

Y en el controlador entonces si recibir el id

```
public ActionResult Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga(int id)
{ ...
```

ó seguir usando el `id_query` con:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Acreditacion_Equipo/Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga?id_query='+  id_query,
```

Y en el controlador

```
public ActionResult Acreditacion_Equipo_Carga(string id_query)
{ ...
```